# Creating schema for Tuple in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

How can I create Pig schema for the below tuple data while loading the relation?

```
]$ cat data

(3,8,9) (4,5,6)

(1,4,7) (3,7,5)

(2,5,8) (9,5,8)
```

I tried the below statement in local mode

```
A = LOAD '/home/cloudera/data' AS (t1:tuple(t1a:int,t1b:int,t1c:int),t2:tuple(t2a:int,t2b:int,t2c:int));
```

If I dump the data, I expected the result

```
DUMP A;

((3,8,9),(4,5,6))

((1,4,7),(3,7,5))

((2,5,8),(9,5,8))
```

But what I get was,

```
((3,8,9),)

((1,4,7),)

((2,5,8),)
```

I am using Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the next work:

```
A = load  '$input' using PigStorage(' ') AS (t1:tuple(t1a:int,t1b:int,t1c:int),t2:tuple(t2a:int,t2b:int,t2c:int));
describe A;
dump A;
```

The dump:

```
((3,8,9),(4,5,6))
((1,4,7),(3,7,5))
((2,5,8),(9,5,8))
```